# How do you fill array inside loop

Tags: php, arrays

My array is

```
$new_arr = array('list');
$arr = Array(0 => Array( 'fruits' => 'apple'),1 => Array( 'fruits' => 'mango'));

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
  $res = array_fill($new_arr,$val);
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

It only fills the index `1`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is the expected result...?

Comment: What do you want your filled array to look like?

Comment: I tried,but values not inserted into list array

Comment: The expected result should be Array('list' => Array('fruits' => 'apple,'fruits' => 'mango'));

Comment: Just in case if you are not particular about the loop and just want to assign the whole $arr to $new_arr, you can use
`$new_arr = $arr;`

Comment: There is no way you can get `Array('list' => Array('fruits' => 'apple,'fruits' => 'mango'));` as an end result... you can only have 1 value per key... the array you want would have 2 values for the key "fruits", that's not possible. You should re-think how you want your end result, I would suggest something more like `Array('list' => Array('fruits' => array(1 => 'apple, 2 => 'mango')));`

Comment: @naomi so its not posible to get that result even any function?i took 48 hours for this and until now i can't find a way to get that result,hopefully others can do that.

Comment: You must rethink how you want your end result. Assigning 2 different values to the same key will always result in only 1 value (always the last one, as it "overwrites" the value every time). Trying to get this result, you will always end up with only `Array('list' => Array('fruits' => 'mango'));`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
$new_arr = array('list');
$arr = Array(0 => Array( 'fruits' => 'apple'),1 => Array( 'fruits' => 'mango'));

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $res = array_push($new_array,$val);
}

Print_r($res);
```

Comment: You know that `$res` is an `int`?

Comment: @Forien `$res`is an `array` not an int

Comment: [Are you REALLY sure? (linked again)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) `Returns the new number of elements in the array.`

Comment: @Forien Yes I'm really sure: `The expected result should be Array('list' => Array('fruits' => 'apple,'fruits' => 'mango')); –  henedina malundras`

Comment: How does that quote says that `array_push` returns not an int? LOL

Comment: I said i want the result like that. $res is integer if you set it to array_push

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]`.

```
$new_arr = array('list'=>array());
$arr = Array(0 => Array( 'fruits' => 'apple'),1 => Array( 'fruits' => 'mango'));

foreach($arr as $key => $val){
  $new_arr['list'][] = $val;
}

Print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: Hello i just want to put the array fruits inside list array like this. Array('list' => Array('fruits' => 'apple,'fruits' => 'mango'));

Comment: @henedinamalundras ok, check it now. You have to set 'list' as a `key` of element inside array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$new_arr = array();
$arr = Array(0 => Array( 'fruits' => 'apple'),1 => Array( 'fruits' => 'mango'));
foreach($arr as $key => $val)
{
 $new_arr['list']['fruits'][] =$val['fruits'];
}


print_r($new_arr);
```

This would give you

```
Array
(
    [list] => Array
        (
            [fruits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => apple
                    [1] => mango
                )

        )

)
```

The output you require, `Array('list' => Array('fruits' => 'apple,'fruits' => 'mango'));` contains identical keys. That doesn't look good.

Comment: Maybe use the variables instead of hardcoding the 'list' and 'fruits' indexes ;)

Comment: Hmmmm how about json encode.make a string and use regix then back decode and fill to list?

Answer (score 0):

The end result you want is not possible to get.

`Array('list' => Array('fruits' => 'apple,'fruits' => 'mango'));`

will always end up being

`Array('list' => Array('fruits' => 'mango'));` because you are using 2 identical keys in the same array.
Try this if you do not believe me:

```
$arr = Array('list' => Array('fruits' => 'apple', 'fruits' => 'mango'));
var_dump($arr);
```

See how the apple disappeared? That's because http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php :

> 1. Note that when two identical index are defined, the last overwrite the first.

Now, if you want to keep all the data and merge them into 1 array, you should change your expected result to: `Array('list' => Array('fruits => Array(0 => 'apple', 1 => 'mango')));`

And one way to accomplish this result would be:

```
$tmp_arr = array();
$arr = Array(0 => Array( 'fruits' => 'apple'),1 => Array( 'fruits' => 'mango'));
foreach($arr as $sub){
    foreach($sub as $key=>$val) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $tmp_arr))
            $tmp_arr[$key] = array();
        $tmp_arr[$key][] = $val;
    }
}
$new_arr = array('list'=>$tmp_arr);
print_r($new_arr);
```